# ColdFusion: isdefined, but throws undefined error

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

```
<cfif ISDEFINED("CALLER.VARIABLES.STRFUNCNAME")>
  <cfparam name="strFuncName" default="#EVALUATE(CALLER.VARIABLES.STRFUNCNAME)#" />
<cfelse>
  <cfparam name="strFuncName" default="" />
</cfif>
```

This code is in one of our CustomTags and is throwing an error on the EVALUATE line.  I'm not sure how that's even possible.

I can do this from the calling page to see that the variable is defined:

```
<cfset VARIABLES.strFuncName = "strFuncName#intModule#"> <!--- intModule = 1188 --->
#VARIABLES.strFuncName#: #EVALUATE(VARIABLES.strFuncName)# <!--- strFuncName1188: Main --->
<CF_CUSTOMTAG> <!--- Tell me Variable strFuncName1188 is undefined. --->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
<cfparam name="strFuncName" default="#EVALUATE('CALLER.VARIABLES.STRFUNCNAME')#" />
```

Comment: Note the single quotes within the evaluate call

Comment: This works.  Can you explain how?  I also found that doing it another way works (see my post)...

Comment: It works because evaluate takes the string that was passed to it and attempts to interpret that string as a dynamic expression.  With the quotes, the string being passed is the name of the variable.  Without the quotes, the string is the content of the variable.  Honestly, it doesn't look like you even need the eval, since the string is static.

Comment: It isn't static at all. Changes depending on what module is being loaded on the page. Thanks a LOT for your help.

Comment: What Jake means by static is: VARIABLES.strFuncName simply evaluates to a string you're creating, ie "strFuncName1188". Now, if strFuncName1188 was *itself* the name of a variable, and you wanted *its* value, that is when you would use Evaluate().

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out…

CALLER.VARIABLES.STRFUNCNAME was only returning "strFuncName####".  So doing an evaluate on that was looking for the variable "strFuncName####" it in the current processing scope, not on the CALLER.

I changed the cfparam to the following and it began working:

```
<cfparam name="strFuncName" default="#EVALUATE("CALLER." & CALLER.VARIABLES.STRFUNCNAME)#" />
```